# Pixi js. Отображение нескольких анимаций сразу

Tags: javascript, pixijs

Проблема в следующем. Я хочу отобразить несколько разных анимаций на экране, но у меня отображается только одна. По отдельности каждая анимация работает как нужно. Вот мой код.

```html
PIXI.settings.SCALE_MODE = PIXI.SCALE_MODES.NEAREST;


let loader = new PIXI.Loader();
const scene_render_1 = new PIXI.Container();
const scene_render_2 = new PIXI.Container();
const scene_render_3 = new PIXI.Container();
const scene_render_4 = new PIXI.Container();
const scene_render_5 = new PIXI.Container();
const scene_render_6 = new PIXI.Container();
const scene_render_7 = new PIXI.Container();
const scene_render_8 = new PIXI.Container();
const scene_render_9 = new PIXI.Container();
const scene_render_10 = new PIXI.Container();
const scene_render_11 = new PIXI.Container();
const scene_render_12 = new PIXI.Container();



let app = new PIXI.Application({
    width: 1280,
    height: 768,
    antialias: true,    
});


app.stage.addChild(
    scene_render_1, scene_render_2, scene_render_3,
    scene_render_4, scene_render_5, scene_render_6,
    scene_render_7, scene_render_8, scene_render_9,
    scene_render_10, scene_render_11, scene_render_12
);


scene_render_1.position.set(0, 0);
scene_render_2.position.set(0, 0);
scene_render_3.position.set(0, 0);
scene_render_4.position.set(0, 0);
scene_render_5.position.set(0, 0);
scene_render_6.position.set(0, 0);
scene_render_7.position.set(0, 0);
scene_render_8.position.set(0, 0);
scene_render_9.position.set(0, 0);
scene_render_10.position.set(0, 0);
scene_render_11.position.set(0, 0);
scene_render_12.position.set(0, 0);

document.body.appendChild( app.view );




PIXI.Loader.shared.add("images/animation_plita.json").load(animation_plita);
function animation_plita() {
  let sheet_animation_plita = PIXI.Loader.shared.resources["images/animation_plita.json"].spritesheet;
  avatar_animation_plita = new PIXI.AnimatedSprite(sheet_animation_plita.animations["idle_plita"]);
  avatar_animation_plita.animationSpeed = 0.15
  avatar_animation_plita.scale.set(2);
  avatar_animation_plita.position.set(180, 576);
  avatar_animation_plita.play();
  scene_render_3.addChild(avatar_animation_plita);
}


PIXI.Loader.shared.add("images/animation_altar.json").load(animation_altar);
function animation_altar() {
  let sheet_animation_altar = PIXI.Loader.shared.resources["images/animation_altar.json"].spritesheet;
  avatar_animation_altar = new PIXI.AnimatedSprite(sheet_animation_altar.animations["idle_altar"]);
  avatar_animation_altar.animationSpeed = 0.15
  avatar_animation_altar.scale.set(2);
  avatar_animation_altar.position.set(400, 200);
  avatar_animation_altar.play();
  scene_render_3.addChild(avatar_animation_altar);
}
```

Comment: `1` — это `единица`, `один` или `одна`? не экономьте, пожалуйста, буквы. они бесплатны. нажмите [edit] и внесите изменения в вопрос.

Comment: Поправил. Имелось ввиду всего одна анимация хотя прописано несколько. Причем если например удалить код  анимации   animation_plita   спокойно отображается     animation_altar и наоборот